# ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, ssl-certificate

I have React and Spring boot web application. My web application is in Windows server 2019. I generated a certificate for my webpage [www.mypage.com](http://www.mypage.com) and registered in IIS manager. When I go to my webpage there is a lock symbol and It is fine. But when I make a request to my backend rest api service. It gives me this error. ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID. I also followed the steps for spring boot certificates.
added certificate to under the resources folder.

```
http.port=8080
server.ssl.key-alias=mydomain
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:KeyStore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
```

When I make rest by using chrome with url. It gives NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID, when I clicked advance, and processed not secure. It shows the data.

I don't know what to do the fix the error.

Comment: is the backend and the rect application running on the same domain?

Comment: Are you using self-signed certificates?

Comment: I bought real ssl certificate then converted to .p12. UI and SERVER ssl certificate domain name should be same. I used same certificate to both of them